# How to automate the assigment of variables from a table in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, plotly

I have a long table with many rows and my goal is to sort this table out to conduct further analysis on the different parameters.

The df looks like this:

```
    datetime                    value   type    description                 name
0   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.22    HLN     HigLowNot                   NO2
1   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.31    HLN     HighLowNot                  CO
2   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   1.15    HLN     HighLowNot                  NO
3   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   1.80    AIS     AllinSep                    NO2
4   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   2.60    AIS     AllinSep                    CO
5   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   2.30    AIS     AllinSep                    NO
```

This is a short form, there are 20 unique names and 2 types.

This is what I do currently:

I sort by typ HLN  `h = df[df['type'] == 'HLN']` and get that specific type in one lon table.

After that I create for each name a subset and after that a pivot table. I want to automate both parts because they have 40 lines in total. Ist that possible?

```
h_NO2 = h[h['name'] == 'NO2'] 
h_NO = h[h['name'] == 'NO']
h_CO = h[h['name'] == 'CO']
```

```
h_NO2_subset = h_NO2.pivot(index ="datetime", columns="description", values = "value")
h_NO_subset = h_NO.pivot(index ="datetime", columns="description", values = "value")
h_CO_subset = h_CO.pivot(index ="datetime", columns="description", values = "value")
```

Comment: `dfs = {name : dataframe for name,dataframe in h.groupby('name') }` should do the trick then `dfs['NO2']` to call the dataframe, if you have many variables use a container that's what they are there for - you can add in any additional logic - such as pivoting into the dict comprehension.

Comment: You can group the table by type and then name. After that, you can create your pivot table.

Comment: @Umar.H thanks for the answer. Where do I place the pivoting, also in the bracket from the dfs?

Comment: `{name : dataframe.pivot(index="datetime", columns="description", values="value") for name,dataframe in h.groupby('name') } ` not tested but that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary as container:

```
dict_h = {i: h[h['name'] == i]
          for i in h['name'].unique()
         }
dict_h_subset = {k: v.pivot(index="datetime",
                            columns="description",
                            values="value")
                 for k,v in dict_h.items()
                }
```

Then access the results by key:

```
dict_h_subset['NO2']
```

output:

```
>>> dict_h
{'NO2':                     datetime  value type description name
 0  2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.22  HLN   HigLowNot  NO2
 3  2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   1.80  AIS    AllinSep  NO2,
 'CO':                     datetime  value type description name
 1  2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.31  HLN  HighLowNot   CO
 4  2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   2.60  AIS    AllinSep   CO,
 'NO':                     datetime  value type description name
 2  2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   1.15  HLN  HighLowNot   NO
 5  2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   2.30  AIS    AllinSep   NO}

>>> dict_h_subset
{'NO2': description                AllinSep  HigLowNot
 datetime                                      
 2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       1.8       0.22,
 'CO': description                AllinSep  HighLowNot
 datetime                                       
 2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       2.6        0.31,
 'NO': description                AllinSep  HighLowNot
 datetime                                       
 2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       2.3        1.15}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I tried it and when I type `dict_h['NO2']` the table is empty and so is the subset.

Comment: Then there is an issue with your original command as I used exactly the same (unless I missed a typo). What is the output of `h['name'].unique()`?

Comment: I ran the code and it works fine for me, please double-check ;)

Comment: My bad, works perfect! Now I check the solution from Umar.H

Comment: One further question. How can I select a specific colum in `dict_h_subset['NO2']`?

Comment: `dict_h_subset['NO2'][COLUMNNAME]`

Comment: That was the first thing I tired but it didn‘t work. I tried it with “ “ and ‘ ‘ both didn‘t work. I wonder why such an easy operation doesn‘t work. I guess today was not a good start in the week for me.:)

Comment: Check again ;) `dict_h_subset['NO2']` is the same as your former `h_NO2`, it is a dataframe and you can use it exactly as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

Import necessary packages:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Prepare the test data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00', 
                                '2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00', 
                                '2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00', 
                                '2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00', 
                                '2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00',
                                '2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00'],
                   'value': [0.22, .031, 1.15, 1.80, 2.60, 2.30],
                   'type': ['HLN', 'HLN', 'HLN', 'AIS', 'AIS', 'AIS'],
                   'description': ['HighLowNot', 'HighLowNot', 'HighLowNot', 'AllinSep', 'AllinSep', 'AllinSep'],
                   'name': ['NO2', 'CO', 'NO', 'NO2', 'CO', 'NO']})
```

Test data:

```
    datetime                    value   type    description name
0   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.220   HLN     HighLowNot  NO2
1   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   0.031   HLN     HighLowNot  CO
2   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   1.150   HLN     HighLowNot  NO
3   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   1.800   AIS     AllinSep    NO2
4   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   2.600   AIS     AllinSep    CO
5   2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   2.300   AIS     AllinSep    NO
```

Loop through the type and name to extract subset:

```
splitted_result = []

# loop the unique items of 'type' column
for type in np.unique(df['type']):    
    # loop the unique items of 'name' column
    for name in np.unique(df['name']):
        print('-------------------')
        print('type : {}, name : {}'.format(type, name))

        # extract rows which has the specific name
        temp = df.loc[((df['type'] == type) & (df['name'] == name))]
        subset = temp.pivot(index ="datetime", columns="description", values = "value")
        print(subset)
        splitted_result.append({f'{type}_{name}_subset': subset})
```

This is the result:

```
-------------------
type : AIS, name : CO
description                AllinSep
datetime                           
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       2.6
-------------------
type : AIS, name : NO
description                AllinSep
datetime                           
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       2.3
-------------------
type : AIS, name : NO2
description                AllinSep
datetime                           
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       1.8
-------------------
type : HLN, name : CO
description                HighLowNot
datetime                             
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00       0.031
-------------------
type : HLN, name : NO
description                HighLowNot
datetime                             
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00        1.15
-------------------
type : HLN, name : NO2
description                HighLowNot
datetime                             
2018-01-01 00:30:00+01:00        0.22
```

Is this what you want exactly? If that, it's my pleasure. Thanks